# how to create a loop for a generator function instead of each next call

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

I don`t understand how exactly should I use loop for to call all operations instead of using 'print (next(generator))

I have a generator function and I need to print all elements in the list

```
def gen(a,b)... #there is a generator function

for i in gen(a,b):
    print (next(gen(a,b)))
```

where is the problem?

Comment: How about `print(i)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is the value produced by your generator. With your current code, you're ignoring `i`, and creating a new generator in each iteration, then taking the first element of that new iterator.

You simply need:

```
for i in gen(a,b):
    print(i)
```